# Confidence interval for given sample size

Tags: r, regression, logistic, sample-size

My data has a binary dependent variable and 3 categorical independent variables•

Population size is 100,000 and we have results for sample size of 1,000 i.e 1% of population.

How can I calculate confidence interval for this sample size in order to have reliability of the sample?

I have searched and tried to use pwr package with R however could  not succeed•

Thank you very much.

Comment: A confidence interval is estimated for a parameter, such as mean, not on the sample size. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know if sample size is big enough to have an estimate on population. Can it be relied?

Comment: Given that you mention the pwr package, I assume you mean to perform some sort of *power analysis*, that is to determine the required sample size to have a certain power of a test?

Comment: Yes. Is there a more suitable method for achieving this?

Comment: You should probably learn more about the subject first, see https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-power-and-power-analysis-in-python/#:~:text=Statistical%20power%20is%20the%20probability,effect%20size%2C%20and%20statistical%20power, and why this is done **before** collecting a sample.